# Modify AOSP and build SDK

Tags: android-source, android-build

When applying the patches of [OpenPDroid](https://github.com/OpenPDroid/OpenPDroidPatches) to the Android 4.4.2_r1 AOSP by doing

```
cd ~/androidsource/

repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.4.2_r1 -g all 
# "-g all" is important to be able to build the sdk

repo sync

cd ~/androidsource/build; git checkout -b openpdroid; patch -p1 < ~/openpdroid_4.4_build.patch
    cd ~/androidsource/libcore; git checkout -b openpdroid; patch -p1 < ~/openpdroid_4.4_libcore.patch
    cd ~/androidsource/packages/apps/Mms; git checkout -b openpdroid; patch -p1 < ~/openpdroid_4.4_packages_apps_Mms.patch
    cd ~/androidsource/frameworks/base; git checkout -b openpdroid; patch -p1 < ~/openpdroid_4.4_frameworks_base.patch
    cd ~/androidsource/frameworks/opt/telephony; git checkout -b openpdroid; patch -p1 < ~/openpdroid_4.4_frameworks_opt_telephony.patch
```

I can build without a problem

```
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_arm-eng
make update-api
make
```

and then I can run a OpenPDroid application that uses the custom API.

However I cannot build

```
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch sdk-eng
make update-api
make sdk
```

I get the following error when doing so:

```
build/core/main.mk:662: *** : Module 'PDroid' in PRODUCT_PACKAGES has nothing to install!.  Stop.
```

When searching for the problem, people suggest that one should just remove the respective Module , in my case 'PDroid'. But would this not eliminate the whole purpose of the patch if I delete PDroid from the PRODUCT_PACKAGES ?

I tried to comment out the checks made in  `build/core/main.mk`. Then I can build the SDK, but then the added packages are not part of the custom SDK (which suggests that indeed nothing has been built for Module 'PDroid').

What is missing so that the new SDK can be created?